# Kotlin2JS with npm / code change gets not reflected

Tags: javascript, npm, kotlin

I have this very basic npm-kotlin example: https://github.com/MikeMitterer/npm-hello-kotlin

If I run “npm run start” it compiles and shows “Servus Kotlin!!Q12" in the browser. If I change Q12 to Q13 webpack compiles but the change gets not reflected. Any ideas??? Thanks

Comment: What's very odd is that kotlinApp.js, kotlin.js, kotlinApp.meta.js - they all show 01.01.70 as their modification date.
Though I created a abc.txt with touch abc.txt and this file shows the correct date

Answer (score 0):

Try running project with disabled caching. Chances are that same .js file is being served.

Comment: yes, DevTools are open and cache is disabled. If I change the index.html the change gets reflected.

Comment: Does this look like an answer to ? there's a comment section please use it.

Comment: Changed it to be more of a response.